# Remove vim before installing vim-gnome?

Tags: vim

Should I remove vim before installing vim-gnome? It seems redundant to leave vim there, but I'm afraid to remove it. (I'm very new to Ubuntu.)

Comment: @heemayl there's an actual `vim` package - it provides `vim.basic`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should you? No, it doesn't make much of a difference. It's only ~2MB either way, so it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many flavours of `vim` installed in you system like `vim-basic`(provided by default), `vim-tiny`, `vim-gnome` etc.

You can then choose which binary to use by giving preference of one over another using `update-alternatives`. `update-alternatives` decides which binary to execute depending on your preference when `vim` is used.

Basically the `vim` binary (`/usr/bin/vim`) is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/vim`, which in turn is a symbolic link to your preferred one (e.g. `/usr/bin/vim.tiny` or `/usr/bin/vim.basic`). You can read [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/233190/216503) to get more idea on this.

So you can install as many flavours of `vim` you want, you just need to choose the one you want to execute by using the preference.