# "qmake" is not recognized

Tags: qt, .profile

I have installed Qt 5.6 from the official website via a *.run file. The installation directory is in my home folder. When I run

```
qmake --version
```

I get the following message:

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

I think the problem is that the operating system does not look for the qmake in the correct directory (I have Qt installed in my home folder).

How can I tell the operating system to search for Qt in my home folder?

Comment: I have two folders in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" named qt4 and qt5. The default searching directory is in qt4, while I have qt5 installed. It does not seem a good choice to create a link in qt4 while I have qt5. There should be a way to tell the operating system to search in the desired folder.

Comment: Well OK hold on a second though. Why did you install via the `.run` file? That is **not** the recommended way to install software on Linux. Why didn't you use `apt-get`?

Comment: apt-get would have updated alternatives, right now it does not know that qt5 is installed

Comment: Well, I was searching for a specific version of Qt and I found it in the official website. There was not a .deb file and I did not know how to select the version of Qt using apt-get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution lies in using [update-alternatives(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html). For more information on the reasoning behind it, refer to [What exactly does `update-alternatives` do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233190/what-exactly-does-update-alternatives-do)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/qmake qmake /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake 100
```

followed by:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config qmake
```

to make sure the qt5 version is being used. This will update `/usr/bin/qmake` to point to the qt5 version.

*A side note:* You may need to check `/usr/bin/` to see if there is already a symlink. If it is not managed by `update-alternatives` then you may need to manually remove or rename it for this to work.

Hope that helps!

Comment: And don't forget to check the right version of the manpage. I linked the LTS, but use the one that applies.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. By the way, I had the Qt installed in my home folder, so the command line that I used is like this: "sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/qmake qmake <QT_DIRECTORY>/bin/qmake 100"

Comment: Yes, I figured you would update the info to be pertinent. Glad it helped.

Comment: This works on KDE neon 5.14. Honestly, I don't know what caused this nor I remember anything I did.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, I get `update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake doesn't exist`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev
```

Followed by:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/qmake qmake /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake 100
```