# Change Java Version from 11 to 8

Tags: java, openjdk

I'm working on some of my projects using Java 11, but some libraries are not available in this version. So I want to move to Java 8. However, I'm not able to remove Java 11 version and install Java 8. In my `usr/lib/jvm` directory both versions of Java are shown (see screenshot).

[image: usr/lib/jvm contents]

How can I change the Java version from 11 to 8?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this answer ? [How to set default Java version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version)

It looks like it can answer your problem. You can have multiple Java versions running on your system and change between them with:

> sudo update-alternatives --config java